# Altering the size of a Hash

Tags: data-structures, hash, bloom-filters

Does removing the leading(or trailing) n bits of any given hash have any negative effects other then increasing the likeliness of collisions? Does appending 2 hashes of the same object with different seeds have have any negative effects?

For some context I am building a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) that has a variable size and would like to either increase or decrease the standard 32/64 bit hashes to fit the required size of the bloom filter

Comment: For decent hash functions, truncating the hash should have no ill effects beyond what you mention. Appending two hashes also sounds pretty benign.